# trigger a release pipeline from target server

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Im kinda new to Devops

i want to create a basic release pipeline, that instead of running on 1 or several servers- would run individually on each developer's machine, and ONLY WHEN THEY CHOOSE TO RUN IT. 
NOT scheduled, and NOT by one person who decides to run it for all developers at a certain time.

that  means each developer would have an agent on their developing machine.

so i figured, each developer would have access to  their own private area on TFS (Azure Devops)
in which they would  (ONLY!!) have access to their own Release pipelines. (several pipelines because there are several environments).

Dose that make sense? is my need common? any other recommended approaches for this need?

Thank You

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: its currently performed by script.  copying files, registring to gac and configure IIS. I want to replace the script with  a Realease pipline.

Comment: they would (ONLY!!) have access to their own Release pipelines. Does this mean view or edit corresponding pipeline? Or just it can only be run with specific one but can edit it?